# SQL - Using a Subselect

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 rows: AccountNum, InvoiceAcc and Blocked. Most rows my table have an InvoiceAcc but not all. AccountNum is the unique identifier and its possible for a number of AccountNum's to have the same InvoiceAcc. Blocked is an int value varying from 0, 1 and 2.

The InvoiceAcc is based off of an AccountNum so think of it as a Parent Office which then has proceeding Child Offices.

For example, a parent office like so:

`AccountNum - 1, InvoiceAcc - null, Blocked - 2` might have a child offices like so:

```
AccountNum - 1-1, InvoiceAcc - 1, Blocked - 0

AccountNum - 1-2, InvoiceAcc - 1, Blocked - 1
```

What I'd like to do is check the InvoiceAcc of a row and its subsequent AccountNum blocked value. So in my example above, If I did a query like so:

```
SELECT BLOCKED FROM CustTable WHERE AccountNum = '1-1'
```

It would return 0 as that is the blocked value. What I'd like it to do is return 2 as that has the higher value and its the parent account. Also, if the parent acc has a blocked value of 1 and the child account which I'm querying has an blocked value of 2, then it should return 2. Im assuming a subselect would be needed here?

It should return the highest blocked value based on either itself or its parents account, if it has a parent account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a write your query like this as only as you only have one level (e.g. parent -> child)

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN child.blocked > COALESCE(parent.blocked,0)
  THEN child.blocked 
  ELSE parent.blocked 
END as blocked
FROM CustTable child 
LEFT JOIN CustTable parent ON child.InvoiceAcc = parent.AccountNum
WHERE child.AccountNum = '1-1'
```

Comment: this is also static for accno=1

Comment: Nop, not If I replace that with a parameter or even remove the where altogether, as this will show the highest block value of each customer

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit messy.
It's the "1-?" that's messing you up.

ParentAccount = 1, SubAccount = 2, would resolve that

Then you could select by ParentAccount with somethimng like

```
Select parent.Blocked From SomeTable parent
inner join SomeTable Children On Parent.ParentAccount = Child.ParentAccount
```

Keep your current structure and you are going to have to come up with a bunch of string functions to extract the A from "A-C"

Comment: Hi, this is the business system that already exsisted before I started! It has thousands of customers so too late to change now!

Comment: Ah well, looks like @Shoaib's answer will be close then. It's not going to be as performant as it could be though. Not the first time you'll be left with nasty bodge, I've done lots of 'em.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
select AccountNum ,(select count(*) from CustTable  where AccountNum like t.AccountNum +'-%') as Totalsubacc from CustTable t where AccountNum not like '%-%'
```